# Use JQuery AJAX Prefilter to Inspect Response Data And Conditionally Forward to 'Error' Event Handler

Tags: json, jquery, error-handling, extending

I may be way off course, but I was wondering if it's possible to use the JQuery [prefilter](http://api.jquery.com/extending-ajax/) functionality and analyze the response data in an Ajax Success and conditionally forward to the `error` event handler in my `ajax` calls based on the existence of certain elements in my returned JSON (error messages).

It would be nice if this was globally set for any ajax function in the page.

Maybe this isn't the best way to go about this; if anyone has an alternative idea, please let me know!

The prefilter:

```
//only run prefilter on ajax calls expecting JSON back in response, would this 
//be the right way to do this? 
$.ajaxPrefilter( "json", function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
    jqXHR.success(function(data, textStatus, jXHR) {
        if( hasErrors(data) ) {
           //forward to error event handler?
        }
    });
});
```

Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
      type:     "POST",
      data:     {  
                    theData: "someData"                    
                },
      url:      theUrl,
      dataType: 'json',
      cache:    false,          
      success:  function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    //do stuff on success
                }
      error:    function ( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                    //I want to do this stuff if data contains errors from server
                } 
 });
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's how I do it: I store the original success function (specific for each request), and then attach another callback. If it didn't have errors, I call the original callback:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
    var originalSuccess = options.success;

    options.success = function (data) {
        if(hasErrors(data)) {
           //forward to error event handler or redirect to login page for example
        }
        else {
            if (originalSuccess != null) {
                originalSuccess(data);
            }
        }   
    };
});
```

Comment: I was using custom handler after each success callback. Now i saw the $.ajaxPrefilter in the jQuery API and saw your response. You made me gain time. Thanks.

Comment: How do you 1. halt all `.done` callbacks, and 2. run `.fail` callbacks, in the `hasErrors(data)` conditional? I tried `jqXHR.reject()` but ended up `jqXHR.reject is not a function`. What exactly you write in the conditional section?

Comment: I utilized a similar methodology to handle multiple successive ajax fires and dealing with rails/backbone CSRF-token handling/setting before returning the response-data to the original ajax success/error callback. Excellent idea and thanks for sharing!