# How to inspect the successful result of a jQuery AJAX request and abort the jQuery.load() before it inserts the content?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am using the `jQuery.load()` method to make an AJAX request and insert some content into my page.

I would like to be able to add some kind of global handler that will inspect the result of my *successful* AJAX request, and then optionally call a global error handler based on the data returned.

I have been able to achieve this for 'normal' `jQuery.get()` requests by using `$.ajaxPrefilter()` to override the provided 'success' method with one that inspects the request. (Found on this StackOverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6373965)

```js
$.ajaxPrefilter(function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
    var originalSuccess = options.success;

    options.success = function (data) {
        if(hasErrors(data)) {
           //forward to error event handler or redirect to login page for example
        }
        else {
            if (originalSuccess != null) {
                originalSuccess(data);
            }
        }   
    };
});
```

My problem is that this method does not work for AJAX requests fired from the `jQuery.load()` method. I've looked in the jQuery source and it's doing this:

```js
jQuery.ajax({ .. })
    .done(function(responseText) {
        // Inserts HTML into DOM.
    })
    .complete(callback);
```

Is there anyway to inspect the result of the *successful* `.ajax()` method and prevent the deferred `.done()` function from being fired?

Ideally, I'd like a solution I can slot into the `.ajaxPrefilter()` method above so that this behaviour is global for the entire site.

Comment: Use success of ajax for that

Comment: Call the handler method as the first line of the done() function, passing it the result of the get, and abort if it's not what you expected.

Comment: `load()` is just a shortcut for `$.get` which is a shortcut for `$.ajax`, so why not use whatever works ?

Comment: @JTravakh Any handler I provide is called _after_ the `.load()` has already executed its `.done()` method and inserted the content into the DOM. I would like to be able to abort the request _after_ the request has returned with `statusText = 'success'` but _before_ the `.load()` method executes the deferred `.done()` callback.

Answer (score 0):

On your server side code, you should be able to display a success response or the data you passed.
You can use firebug console (for firefox) to display the ajax results. Alternatively you can use chrome developer tools. In your console, just activate LogXMLHttpRequests by right clicking on it.

The network inspector of firebug and chrome developer tools also displays Ajax responses in the XHR tab.

Comment: I can see the ajax response quite successfully, it contains the data I'm expecting it to. However, it is a 'successful' request, the data is returned OK, but I would like to prevent the default behaviour of `.load()`. The `.load()` method is quite happily taking that data and automatically inserting it into the page. I would like it not to, for a subset of 'successful' requests.

Comment: You should be using jQuery.ajax instead of jQuery.load . the .load function is for automatically placing the data in the element while the .ajax lets you manipulate the process and it even lets you handle some ajax errors